# extrusion lost when importing kmz to google maps

Tags: google-maps, import, 3d, kmz

I'm importing a .kmz file into google maps, however google maps only displays a 2D projection of the path and seems incapable of displaying variation in altitude. Is that simply a limitation of the program, or is there a way to retrieve and present the height (typically displayed as a transparent vertical green rectangle with vertical yellow bars running through it in google earth)?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [KML Elements Supported in Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps) in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

KML has some limitations in Google Maps.
In particular, extrude element is **not supported** in Google Maps.

Reference: KML Elements Supported in Google Maps
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps

You could instead use the [Google Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/) to embed Google Earth in a web page if that is what you want to do and maintain the 3-D look and feel.